# Is this an equivalence relation?

Tags: relations, set-partition

I think the wording is throwing me off, and I also haven't done math in 4 months so basically my mind is scrambled eggs.

> Let $\sim$ be a relation on $\Bbb Z$ defined by letting $m \sim n$ if $mn>0$. Is $\sim$ an equivalence relation?

I would say no, as $m$ or $n$ could be $0$, because $0$ is an element of $\Bbb Z$ and the union of the cells of the partition must equal the original set, but the union doesn't include $0$. Am I right? The word "if" for some reason is boggling my mind.

Comment: Mik, we say `if` in definitions and basically just mean `if and only if`. It's simply a distinction between a definition and an equivalent condition (@dfeuer, perhaps your edit should reflect the original phrasing). Also, if you solve your own question, I think it's more than acceptable to answer it (it could help with your reputation).

Comment: You're right, @JonathanY.; I was going for clarity and accidentally made it clearer than intended.

Comment: Mik, an important lesson is that teasing apart long sentences and rewriting them as separate little pieces can really help you figure out what they mean.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct: It is not true that $0 \sim 0$, since $0 \cdot 0 = 0$. So the relation is not reflexive.